# Is it possible to override a method from an existing class using Dexmaker?

Tags: android, bytecode-manipulation, dex

Is it possible to change at runtime the behaviour of a method from a class already loaded using [Dexmaker](http://code.google.com/p/dexmaker/), by proxing or generating code?

**UPDATE**

Just a remark: I want to add a method/modify existing one from my own application, not from the android framework.

Comment: The real question would prbably be if Dalvik will let you replace a class it already knows about when using a dex class loader.  At least during the loading of apk, it will not - if you put duplicates of platform classes in your app, you'll see in logcat that they are being rejected.

Comment: @Chris Stratton That clarifies some of my doubts. What if I create a jar file on runtime containing such a duplicate class from my own application, does Dalvik still rejects it or it will pick up the "overrinding" class?

Comment: Presumably if you could get yours loaded first during the startup of zygote it would reject the original.  But that would effect every child process of zygote on the system which is to say all apps and most of the platform - and it could break ones that were shipped only in dexopt form (against the original) just as changing a framework class could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is not possible.

You could create a new class that extends the original, or possibly even make a copy of the class, with a new name and a tweaked implementation. But you can't replace an existing class.

Your best bet is probably to extract out the code that you might want to modify into a separate class, and then pass in an instance of that class to whatever uses it. And then, if you need to create a new implementation, you can subclass it and pass in the subclass instead.

Comment: Is there an example on how to do it? It seems very complicated.